# SABR Implied Vol: Normal Approximation vs Log-Normal Approximation

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, sabr

I am having trouble understanding the difference between the normal and log-normal implied volatilities from Hagans SABR model: http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/SABR.pdf.

As far as i understand the main result presented by Hagan is the implied volatility formula given by equation (2.17a) in that paper. However, upon reading the appendices i have become confused at the difference between the normal implied volatility and the lognormal implied volatility and how the value of $\beta$ effects this. The main result presented by Hagan is the Black implied volatility obtained using the SABR option price formulas and the black option pricing formulas. There are a few things i don't understand:

1. For what values of $\beta$ is the Black (log normal) implied volatility formula for SABR option prices presented by Hagan valid for?
2. What is the normal implied volatility formula and for what values of $\beta$ is the normal implied volatility valid for?
3. Hagan also presents implied $\textit{normal}$ volatility for Black's model, but i thought Black's model was for log normal?
4. Are the Black (log normal) implied volatilities and normal implied volatilities valid for the same range of values of $\beta$, or different ones?

Initially, i thought that Hagan's lognormal approximation of the implied (Black) volatility was valid for $0 < \beta \leq 1$ due to the fact that Hagan says if $\beta = 0$ this represents the "stochastic normal model". But i am not sure anymore.

In general, i am confused at the difference between the normal and log normal implied vols and what role beta plays in determining these. Any help in understanding this would be great, thank a lot.

Comment: "Hagan also presents implied normal normal volatility".... can you point out where it is presented?

Comment: Sure, equation (A. 63) in appendix A from linked the paper. It has a paragraph before it starting with: "We can obtain the implied normal volatility for Black’s model".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to answer all of your questions, but let me give it a go.

1. I don't have a qualified answer to this one. In practice however $\beta$ is always bounded such that $\beta \in [0,1]$ (0 and 1 both included). see SABR chapter in Derman & Miller (2006). But as far I know, $\beta$ is not bounded in the original paper so in theory it can take any non-negatve value and the pricing formula should hold.
2. Set $\epsilon=1$ and see equation A.67!
3. The implied *NORMAL* volatility is that level of volatility that will generate the option price when you use the Bachellier pricing formula. see equation A.54a.

Now for the last part of your post:

Don't confuse distribution of the asset with the implied volatilities. When $\beta=0$ then the asset is stochastic normal *conditioned* on the volatility process.

*"...if one were to apply the log normal implied vol formula but with $\beta=0$ does it then become stochastic normal instead?"*

Once agian, these two things have nothing to do with each other! The *implied log-normal volatility* is simply a phrase we use because it is connected to Black-Scholes/Blacks model where the asset is a GBM hence log-normal. So yes, the formula for *implied log-normal volatility* also holds for $\beta=0$

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. For point 1 when you say between 0 and 1, are 0 and 1 inclusive in that range? If so, since $\beta = 0$ corresponds to the stochastic normal process, if one were to apply the log normal implied vol formula but with $\beta = 0$ does it then become stochastic normal instead?  I think you make a good point about me confusing the asset distribution with the implied volatilities, this is likely where i am getting stuck.

Comment: .... se edited version of my answer

Comment: In the overall picture, the answer is yes! However. Be carefull with the conclusions about the distribution of the asset because the the asset distribution is conditioned on the volatility. I personally don't know what we can conclude about the distribution when $\beta=1$ or $0$. That is a separate question. But everything else is correct.